# Загрузка картинок в базу данных на Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Я вот попытался сделать проект на Code First, позволяющий пользователю  загружать картинки в базу данных. Создал классы моделей и  класс контекста , потом начал создавать контроллер. Я выбрал шаблон "MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework".Определил  Model class, определил Data context class, нажал кнопку "Add", и вышла такая ошибка-"Не удалось извлечь метаданные  для ImageUploadCodeF.Models.Product..  One or more errors were detected in model generation."И далее мне говорилось ,что в моей модели нет ключей, как я понял.
Вот класс Product:

```
using System;


 using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

 namespace ImageUploadCodeF.Models
 {
   public class Product
   {

     public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }
}
 }
```

Вот класс Category:

```
using System;


 using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;

   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


    namespace ImageUploadCodeF.Models
   {
   public class Category
    {
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CateName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
   }
```

Вот класс DataContext:

```
 using System;


 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Data.Entity;

 namespace ImageUploadCodeF.Models
{
   public class DataContext : DbContext
   {

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   }
  }
```

Честно говоря, я этот проект пишу в учебных целях . Вы можете написать мне, как сделать такую вещь ?

Comment: Уберите из модели `Product` поле `public int CategoryId { get; set; }`, т.к. Code First за вас создаст поле `Category_Id`, т.к. вы указали в модели `public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }`. Либо вы ошиблись и хотели сделать `public virtual IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Стыдно признаться ,но для того чтобы создать ProductsController, оказалось достаточно нажать " Сборка/Собрать решение ".